# How to handle a path's subdirectory if a subpath is not found?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've just started learning react.

I am doing a sample program about react routing.

Here is my codes:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import SignUp from "./components/SignUp.jsx";
import Login from "./components/Login.jsx";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.jsx";

const NotFound = () => <h1>Page Not Found</h1>;

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>      
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="/navigation" element={<Navbar />} /> 
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is the codes for `server.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("public/index.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("App started on port 3000");
});
```

`package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "topcoder-skill-builder-reactjs-easy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "compile": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js` file

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: { app: ["./src/App.jsx"] },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader" 
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      name: "vendor",
      chunks: "all"
    }
  }
};
```

My problem is about making the app render the `NotFound` component if the subpath of a route path that is defined is not present.

For example if I entered the url `localhost:3000/signup/something` I was expecting the app to render the `NotFound` component because I did not define the `something` component but instead it just renders a blank page. Why is that? How can I fix this?

I am using react-router-dom v6.8.2

Comment: It depends which version of react router you are using. Try using the index property. Actually try this example: https://medium.com/duomly-blockchain-online-courses/how-to-set-the-default-route-in-reactjs-beda7255cbf8

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code and I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. The code is worked as I'd expect it to. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-handle-a-paths-subdirectory-if-a-subpath-is-not-found-vpylm9?file=/src/App.js) demo. How are you running/serving the app? Perhaps you've an issue there.

Comment: @DrewReese I've added the `server.js` codes in my post

Comment: @DrewReese when I entered the `localhost:3000/something` it correctly renders the `NotFound` component since there is no `something` component that is defined. But if I entered the `localhost:3000/something/another` it just shows a blank page.

In the codesandbox demo that you've provided it really runs accordingly as I've expected it to be. I really don't get what's my error in this

Comment: @DrewReese I've also added the `package.json` file and `webpack,config.js` file in my post. Sorry if I've added something that seems unnecessary for this. I just really don't understand what and where my error is.

Comment: @DrewReese I've copied your codes from codesandbox, the `/signup/something` correctly renders the `NotFound` component, but if I append some characters after `something` like this: `/signup/something/aaa/a`it starts to render a blank page again.

When I do this `/signup/something/aaa/a` in the codesandbox link you've provided it correctly renders the `NotFound` page, but when I do this in my computer locally it doesn't work as I wanted it to be.

Comment: Can you post your SignUp.jsx? Also what happens when you directly visit `localhost:3000/signup` without clicking on a Link? Does it correctly load the signup page? What about the navigation route? Does visiting `localhost:3000/navigation/something` also shows a blank page?

Comment: @Usaid yeah when I directly visit `localhost:3000/signup` it correctly loads the signup page. My problem is rendering the `NotFound` page to a path that I've not defined and instead it just shows a blank page

Comment: @Usaid `localhost:3000/navigation/something` also shows a blank page

Comment: I still use Create React App for all my apps so I don't need to mess with webpack (*i.e. I'm pretty unfamiliar with manual webpack stuff*), but see if adding a `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true },` in your webpack config helps. It seems a lot of configurations need it for `react-router-dom` when running locally.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah I've used create-react-app and it does work properly as I've wanted it but I want to learn to configure it manually. I've read a lot all over the net and watched some videos from YouTube and said that it's not good to use create-react-app on real life projects.

Comment: @robert In your server.js you are running an express app on port 8000, are you using it to serve your react app or are you running a separate webpack devserver on port 3000?

Comment: @DrewReese I've added `devServer` in my `webpack.config.js` still doesn't work as I've wanted it

Comment: @Usaid sorry I forgot to edit my post. I'm just using port 3000 - `localhost:3000`

Comment: "I've read a lot all over the net and watched some videos from YouTube and said that it's not good to use create-react-app on real life projects." - Hmmm, that is news to me. 5+ years in web development and I've come to hold the opinion that the React developers more or less know what they are doing and only to eject and manage all the webpack stuff myself if I had a compelling need to. Using CRA has always just worked for all my use cases, including production code for the apps I develop with the companies I contract with. I'm bowing out though, best of luck on your journey.

Comment: I've also asked this question in ChatGPT, and GPT says I should add route path like this
`/signup/*` to handle undefined subpaths of `signup` route. Still doesn't work lol

And it seems that GPT current knowledge about react-router-dom is version 5.8 something. 

Any ideas how I can solve this thing? lol

Comment: @robert So you are serving your app through express server running on 3000? It seems like express serves you blank page on undefined paths. Also how is webpack compiling it? Do you run `npm run compile` after every edit? You should setup a webpack middleware as described [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-middleware) so express automatically compiles your code before serving

Comment: @Usaid yeah I always run `npm run compile` after every edit

Comment: I don't know what happened but for some reason it seems to work now as I've wanted it. I didn't change anything in my codes, I just turned off my computer for a few minutes and after I turn it on and run it again it started to work now as it should lol. Thanks for all the help guys, really appreciate it!!!